# In CUDA, is there a way to ensure the consistence of FP maths in the same program?

Tags: cuda, floating-point, gpu, nvidia

Is there a way to ensure that:

if `a==b` then `devfun(a)==devfun(b)`;

where `devfun()` is a device function involves some floating point maths ops (e.g. polynomials) and returns floating point results, `a` and `b` are floating point variables.

I don't care about cross-implentation consistence (e.g. different compiler/different OS/different driver versions or different compiler options), I only care about, within the same building/program, at runtime, can it ensure that during each function call, the result returned by `devfun()` are consistent in a way such that as long as `a==b`, `devfun(a)==devfun(b)`?

I am talking about SM2.0+ hardware and CUDA 5.0+, just in case being relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your numbers `a` and `b` represent properly normalized IEEE-754 representation floating point numbers and that niether `a` nor `b` is a `NaN` value.  Let's also assume `a` and `b` are both 32-bit, or else `a` and `b` are both 64-bit (IEEE-754 floating point representations).

In that case, I believe the (ISO C/C++, or CUDA C/C++) floating point test for equality (`==`) will return TRUE when the two numbers `a` and `b` are bitwise identical (and FALSE otherwise).

Under the TRUE case, with one exception, I believe it is safe to assume that `devfun(a) == devfun(b)` without any additional conditions except the obvious ones: there is no difference in the behavior of `devfun` on either side of the `==` operation, that is, it's the same code, compiled in the same way, executed under the same conditions (e.g. other variables that may be taking part in `devfun`, same GPU type, etc.), just as you've indicated in your question: "same building/program".

The one exception is if the result of `devfun(a)` is `NaN`, since (IEEE-754) `NaN != NaN`.

It would be interesting (to me) if you think you have a piece of code that disproves this assertion.

Perhaps floating point ninjas will come along and correct me.

Perhaps also I would be remiss if I did not say something about the hazards of floating point comparisons.  If you're not familiar with this (most folks would *never* recommend performing a test `a==b` on two floating point numbers) you can find many questions about it on SO.

For the same reasons that floating point equality comparison (`==`) in general is unwise, I think relying on the above assertion, even if it's true, is unwise.  Let me give you one example.

Suppose you compile code for architecture `sm_20`.  Now you run the code on an `sm_21` device.  This one simple variation could result in a JIT-compile at runtime.  Now you are no longer running the same code, and all bets are off.

So, again, even if the above is true, I think it's unwise for you to rely on such a statement:

```
if a==b, then devfun(a) == devfun(b)
```

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer, I know the problem with floating point, for your example, I guess I have to include `__CUDA_ARCH__` to ensure the function wont run on hardware other than it is programmed to.

Comment: -0 == 0, but code that extracts the sign bit will give different results...